# Huffman decoding function

Tags: c#, compression, huffman-code

I try to implement `Huffman` encoding compression algorithm. The `Encode` function works for me but when i use decode function didn't give me a right result. I write the output from encoding function in text file and read it to pass to decode function  when i try to solve the same problem with myself the result different from the algorithm code result, what's is the wrong ?
this is my encode function

```
public static void GenerateCode(Node parentNode, string code)
{
  if (parentNode != null)
  {
    GenerateCode(parentNode.leftChild, code + "0");

    if (parentNode.leftChild == null && parentNode.rightChild == null)
      Console.WriteLine(parentNode.data + "{" + code + "}");
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("E:\\test.txt", code);
    GenerateCode(parentNode.rightChild, code + "1");
  }
}
```

and this is the decode function

```
public static void DecodeData(Node parentNode, Node currentNode, int pointer, string input)
{
  if (input.Length == pointer)
  {
    if (currentNode.leftChild == null && currentNode.rightChild == null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(currentNode.data);
    }
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    if (currentNode.leftChild == null && currentNode.rightChild == null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(currentNode.data);
      DecodeData(parentNode, parentNode, pointer, input);
    }
    else
    {
      if (input.Substring(pointer, 1) == "0")
      {
        DecodeData(parentNode, currentNode.leftChild, ++pointer, input);
      }
      else
      {
        DecodeData(parentNode, currentNode.rightChild, ++pointer, input);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my calling for the two function

```
GenerateCode(parentNode1, "");

string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\\test.txt");
DecodeData(parentNode1, parentNode1, 0, contents);
```

Comment: This GenerateCode method just saves existing tree into file; you're missing the Encode method; also general pointer - check out http://snipd.net/huffman-coding-in-c

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar i know that my code just save the tree,  i show the link you put in the comment i want to know how i improve my code i you can help me with a small code or demo to show that. and thanks for your help

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/then-a-miracle-occurs-cartoon.png

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you expect and what `C#` produces